# Question on Frobenius Norm Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I am working on the matrix computation book by Golub and Van Loan and I am unable to prove the following equation.

$$\left\|E\left(I-\frac{ss^T}{s^Ts}\right)\right\|_F^2 = \|E\|_F^2 - \frac{\|Es\|^2_2}{s^Ts}$$

where $s\in \mathbb R^{n}$ and $E \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}.$

I have tried using the $\left\|\cdot\right\|_2$ bounds along with the inequality but cannot get the $-$ sign.  Some insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an application of the definitions
\begin{eqnarray}
 \left\| E\left(I -\dfrac{ss^T}{s^Ts}\right)\right\|^2_F & = & \mathrm{tr}\left[\left(E\left(I -\dfrac{ss^T}{s^Ts}\right)\right)^T\left(E\left(I -\dfrac{ss^T}{s^Ts}\right)\right)\right]\\
& = & \mathrm{tr}\left[\left(I -\dfrac{ss^T}{s^Ts}\right)^TE^T E\left(I -\dfrac{ss^T}{s^Ts}\right)\right]\\
& = & \mathrm{tr}\left[E^T E\left(I -\dfrac{ss^T}{s^Ts}\right)\left(I -\dfrac{ss^T}{s^Ts}\right)^T\right]\\
& = & \mathrm{tr}\left[E^TE\right]-\mathrm{tr}\left[2\cdot\dfrac{E^TEss^T}{s^Ts}- \dfrac{E^TE(ss^T)^2}{(s^Ts)^2}\right]\\
& = & \mathrm{tr}\left[E^TE\right]-\mathrm{tr}\left[2\cdot\dfrac{Es(Es)^T}{s^Ts}- \dfrac{E^TE((s^Ts)ss^T)}{(s^Ts)^2}\right]\\
& = & \mathrm{tr}\left[E^TE\right]-\mathrm{tr}\left[2\cdot\dfrac{Es(Es)^T}{s^Ts}- \dfrac{E^TEss^T}{s^Ts}\right]\\
& = & \mathrm{tr}\left[E^TE\right]-\mathrm{tr}\left[\dfrac{Es(Es)^T}{s^Ts}\right]\\
& = & \left\|E\right\|_F^2 - \dfrac{\left\| Es\right\|_2^2}{s^Ts}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Wow thanks a lot forgot about the trace definition.